# To convert to EXCEL and CSV

Tags: csv, transform, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

how I can convert this structure in CSV

```
[
    {
    "test": "7799"
  },
  {
    "Id": "sys",
    "test": 7799
  },
  {
    "ver": "1.0",
    "group": "v"
  },
  {
    "testHashtag":"age"
   },
   {
   "testHashtag": "age2",
   },
   {
   "testHashtag":"age3"
   },
   {
   "testHashtag": "age5"
  }
  {
    "temp": "id"
  },
  {  
  "temp":  "id2"
  },
  {
     "temp": "id3"
  }
 ]
```

I was trying this:  `payload reduce (element,acc={}) -> acc ++ element`
and then I was doing like this

```
testHastag: payload.testHastag[0] ++ "/" ++ payload.testHastag[1]
```

But I have problem with testHasting because it's takes only first value.
It's should looks like this in CSV:

```
test;id;test;ver;gropup;testHastag;temp
7799;sys;7799;1.0;v,age/age2/age3/age5;id2/id3
```

Comment: That is not valid CSV output, there cannot be nested data. Each row  is a single record. You would have to repeat `test;id;test;ver;gropup,` for each `testHastag;temp` combination.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver
 Hi, I change my payload which I would like to save to CSV. In this payload I have the same key "testHastag" and "temp" but different value. And now it's save me to CSV only first value from "testHastag" and first from "temp". But I would like all value.

Comment: I believe he was referring to the output rather than the input. As it is now age2 goes into the first column. You can not just skip fields in CSV. At the least you should include the separators.

Comment: Having said that, the inputs shown are not well aligned with the output and how DataWeave processes CSVs, which make an answer more difficult. What happens if you have additional rows, for example for `group`?

Comment: @aled Hi I changed my question. I find the way to put all values in one row but it's not perfect because I don't know how many value I will have with the key testHastag. Could you help me how I could do this dynamic? Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Can you change the input to another structure?

Comment: @aled Hi yes I can change but the key of the value need be the same. If I will have three key temp I need have all the value from the key temp.  I would like to looks like this: 
test;id;test;ver;gropup;testHastag;temp
7799;sys;7799;1.0;v,age/age2/age3/age5;id2/id3